# ASP.NET MVC - Check if trans_no exists in the DB after uploading excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel, duplicates

I have a problem about the duplicate entries in my database. My system doesn't have any code about it.

Do you guys have any idea on how to check if the trans_no already exists when I'm uploading the excel file?

I am using ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: you need to be more specific about your problem and you should provide us some code.

Comment: what you want? do you ant to check the condition from excel sheet?or database?

Comment: what is `trans_no` where it is ? in databse? and what is your condition.you want to check some thing before uploading file?

Comment: I want to check if the trans_no from the excel file already exists in the database by uploading the excel file in my system. @Ramesh Rajendran

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have any code. I just want to know if you guys have and you can share it to me.

Comment: I want to check if the trans_no (transaction number) already exists before uploading it. If it exists in the DB, the system shouldn't add the data. The excel file of course does have the trans_no column and also the table. @Sudhakar Tillapudi

Answer (score 0):

If your data size is not too big.  You can use the countif formula.  The way it will work is you have to enter this formula in the data to be uploaded against the data that is already uploaded.

For this function to work you would need both the data to be updated and the data that is already uploaded in excel sheets.

Ex.  =Countifs(uploadedDataEntireColumn,DataToBeUploadedTheValueinSameRowOnly)

This is a very popular function, so lot of help should be available online

Sandesh :)